# Proving inequalities.

Tags: calculus

(Help would be greatly appreciated, I'm at somewhat of a dead end here! Thank you in advance.)

Given that a,b are positive, real numbers: the arithmetic mean 'A' is defined as (a+b)/2, the geometric mean 'G' as square root (ab) and the harmonic mean 'H' as (2ab)/(a+b). Show that H(a,b) <= G(a,b) <= A(a,b) and the case for equality '=' is valid only when a=b.

Comment: MS requires every question raiser to have at least some thoughts on that instead of asking for homework answer.

Answer (score 1):

Notice $$ (\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b})^2 = a - 2\sqrt{ab} + b  \geq 0$$

By trivial inequality $x^2 \geq 0 $

$$ \therefore a + b \geq 2\sqrt{ab} \implies \frac{a + b }{2} \geq \sqrt{ab}$$

To see the other inequality, we again use  $(\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b})^2 = a - 2\sqrt{ab} + b  \geq 0 $

$$ \therefore a + b \geq 2 \sqrt{ab} = \frac{2ab}{\sqrt{ab}} \implies \sqrt{ab} \geq \frac{2ab}{a+b}$$

Therefore,

$$ \frac{a + b }{2} \geq \sqrt{ab} \geq \frac{2ab}{a+b}$$

In general, we have if $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^{\geq0}$ for all $i$

> $$ \sum^n \frac{x_i}{n} \geq ( \prod^nx_i)^{\frac{1}{n}} \geq
>  \frac{n}{\sum^n \frac{1}{x_i} } $$

(proof?)

Comment: That should be in general for $x_i \ge 0$, otherwise nice...

Comment: +1 This is the skill we need to teach calculus students in the US for them to ever be able to get past pencil pushing and calculator problems. Very nicely done!